# Can't find variable: FirebaseStorage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I want to upload image on firebase. When I navigate to my Photo Component I have **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FirebaseStorage**

I followed [firebase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file)

My code:

```
// Photo Component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

import firebase from '@firebase/app'

export default class Photo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    var storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    var storageRef = storage.reference;
    var file = Uri.fromFile(File("images/image1.png"))
    var photoStored = storageRef.child("images")
    uploadTask = photoStored.putFile(file)

    return (
      <View> 
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
     )
  }
```

```
// App Component
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth'

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX"
});

export class App extends React.Component {
...
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Photo');
...
```

Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: What library are you using for firebase storage?

Comment: @10101010: firebase : 5.5.8 and firebase-storage : 16.0.5

Comment: For react-native I highly recommend using https://rnfirebase.io/. I am not sure how well the web sdk works with react-native.

Comment: As for your question `FirebaseStorage` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks 10101010. As said Cool7 I was applying wrong doc. If I can't get rid of my problems I will have a look to the library you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring the Native Android Docs and you have mixed up the thing here:

To upload a file on Firestorge using the following code:

```
firebase
      .storage()
      .ref('/uploadOk.jpeg')
      .putFile(
        `${firebase.storage.Native.DOCUMENT_DIRECTORY_PATH}/ok.jpeg`
      )
      .then(successCb)
      .catch(failureCb);
```

For more details you can refer the following link:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/storage/reference/Reference.md#putfile

Comment: You are right, I was trying to apply Native Android docs to my React Native app. I tried what you suggest but trigger: *undefined is not a function (evaluating '_app.default.storage()'). Do you know if I forget to import something so storage() is undefined ?

Comment: try to import firebase from the proper package like : import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

Comment: @Me_Will Cool7 is assuming that you are using the library I linked.

Comment: You can start here for firebase setup in app: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup

Comment: Yes, that is the correct and up to date library for react-native firebase.